# Sending events to JS React Native

Tags: objective-c, react-native

I implemented on Objective C events emitter to React Native, where I created an emitter class which sends events to react native and seems to work:

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>

@interface PlayerEventsEmitter : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule>

@end


#import "PlayerEventsEmitter.h"

@implementation PlayerEventsEmitter
{
   bool hasListeners;
}

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
   static PlayerEventsEmitter *sharedInstance = nil;
   static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
   dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
       sharedInstance = [super allocWithZone:zone];
   });
return sharedInstance;
}


- (NSArray<NSString *> *)supportedEvents {
    return @[@"onMediaLoaded", @"onPlaying", @"onPause", @"onError", @"onEnded", @"onBuffering", @"onTimeUpdate", @"onStateUpdate"];
}

- (void)startObserving {
    hasListeners = YES;
}

- (void)stopObserving {
    hasListeners = NO;
}

- (void)sendEventName:(NSString *)eventName body:(id)body {
   if (hasListeners) {
      [self sendEventWithName:eventName body:body];
}
}

@end
```

But on JS when I do this:

```
import {NativeEventEmitter, NativeModules} from 'react-native';
import isFunction from 'lodash/isFunction';
import noop from 'lodash/noop';
import createMiddleware from './middleware';

const nativeAdapter = NativeModules.RNNativePlayerAdapter; //  eslint-disable-line
const { ModuleWithEmitter } = NativeModules;
const eventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(ModuleWithEmitter);

const onMediaLoaded = (event) => {
  console.log(event);
}

const onPlaying = (event) => {
  console.log(event);
}

const subscription1 = eventEmitter.addListener('onMediaLoaded', onMediaLoaded);
const subscription2 = eventEmitter.addListener('onPlaying', onPlaying);

export default class NativeAdapter {
  constructor() {
    console.log('nativeAdapter: ', nativeAdapter);
    console.log('NativeModules: ', NativeModules);

     this.subscription = eventEmitter.addListener(
       'onMediaLoaded',
         (onMediaLoaded) => {
             console.log('onMediaLoaded');
        }
      );
    }
}
```

I get an error:
"Native module cannot be null"

And I followed exactly the documentation:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios

Please help.

Thanks,
Claudiu

Comment: can you add a condition that

 if(NativeModules) {
 const { ModuleWithEmitter } = NativeModules;
const eventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(ModuleWithEmitter);
}

Comment: It doesn't work, same error.

Comment: Use RCTBridgeModule.h
 * Calling `NativeModules.ModuleName.doSomethingAsync(aString)` from react native and receive by same method name within this RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(method name:params)

Answer (score 0):

That error means you haven't linked your module. Modules are basically libraries, so you have to link them to the main project. Check this:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios